# why doesn't the CSS[margin-right] not getting applied in the html?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Code:

```css
table {
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="table-responsive-md">
  <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-sm text-light">

    <caption>The todo-List</caption>

    <thead class="thead-dark">
      <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>Date of Diclaration</th>
        <th>Date of Finish</th>
        <th>Target To Be Nailed</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
      <tr class="bg-primary">
        <td>1</td>
        <td>13 nov 1998</td>
        <td>13 nov 2019</td>
        <td>Meet her</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="bg-dark ">
        <td>1</td>
        <td>13 nov 1998</td>
        <td>13 nov 2019</td>
        <td>Meet her</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

I know that what I am about to ask you would be silly but please help me okey!!.
I am not able to make a margin right for the table while margin-left is working perfectly and I have tried to change it to margin-right: 50px or 5%;
but Nothing is working out..so please suggest some change to get it right..thanks

Comment: `margin-right` is working. You need another element besides the table to see the margin. Check the devtools which shows the right margin.

Comment: see print screen from F12:https://i.stack.imgur.com/9JB4j.png

Comment: you worte `5%` in question but in code set `5px` so chang it to precent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.table-responsive-md{
  padding-left:5px;
  padding-right:5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="table-responsive-md">
  <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-sm text-light">

    <caption>The todo-List</caption>

    <thead class="thead-dark">
      <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>Date of Diclaration</th>
        <th>Date of Finish</th>
        <th>Target To Be Nailed</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
      <tr class="bg-primary">
        <td>1</td>
        <td>13 nov 1998</td>
        <td>13 nov 2019</td>
        <td>Meet her</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="bg-dark ">
        <td>1</td>
        <td>13 nov 1998</td>
        <td>13 nov 2019</td>
        <td>Meet her</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Because of the table is full width, margin right is not working. If you use padding left and padding right on parent tag, you will do what you want.